# Trouble with Login using Spring Boot and JDBC Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

My build.gradle file:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '2.4'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/release" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/release" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    runtime("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
    runtime("postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901.jdbc4")
    runtime("net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1")
    runtime("javax.servlet:jstl:1.2")
    runtime("org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs")
}
```

My controller file:

```
package com.mycompany.springtutorialapp;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Controller
@RestController
public class RootController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView defaultPage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Welcome to Spring Tutorial Web Application");
        model.addObject("message", "Home page of Spring Tutorial WebApp");
        model.setViewName("index");
        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Login Form - Database Authentication");
        model.addObject("message", "This page is for ROLE_ADMIN only!");
        model.setViewName("admin");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
                              @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
        }
        model.setViewName("login");

        return model;

    }

    //for 403 access denied page
    @RequestMapping(value = "/403", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView accesssDenied() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

        //check if user is login
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
            model.addObject("username", userDetail.getUsername());
        }

        model.setViewName("403");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public ModelAndView greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="User") String name) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("greeting");
        String str = "Hello " + name + "!";
        mav.addObject("message", str);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

My security config:

```
package com.mycompany.springtutorialapp;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private DataSource authDBDataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource){
        authDBDataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(authDBDataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select name, password, enabled from public.jdbcauth where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select name, role from public.jdbcauth where username=?");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("name").passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
                .csrf();
    }

}
```

Login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
.error {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
}

.msg {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #31708f;
    background-color: #d9edf7;
    border-color: #bce8f1;
}

#login-box {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>

    <h1>Spring Security Login Form (Database Authentication)</h1>

    <div id="login-box">

        <h2>Login with Username and Password</h2>

        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
            <div class="error">${error}</div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
            <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
        </c:if>

        <form name='loginForm'
          action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='post'>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                  value="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />

        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My database is setup correctly. The POSTGRES JDBC drivers are also in path (I was able to create another DAO, connect to the database and query the authtable described above).

When I type in localhost:8080/login, the login screen is displayed correctly. However, after filling in credentials, if I hit the submit button, I get the following error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Jun 22 12:02:03 IST 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

On the server console, I get the following log:

```
2015-06-22 12:04:01.846  WARN 9178 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First your parameter should be named `name` not `username` (this is your own configuration setup!). You should post to `/login` (the default when using java config) instead of `/j_spring_security_check`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. That was indeed the problem - i.e. I had to forward to /login rather than /j_spring_security_check. Can you please convert your comment into an answer so that I can accept it? (I also changed all the occurrences of "username" to "name" - silly gaffe on my part)

Comment: @M.Deinum As an addon question, when I fill the details and hit submit, it shows me the login?error page everytime. Even when I enter details that match what I have entered in my database. I don't have any errors on the server console now so I am guessing all the SQL is working fine. Any idea what might be going wrong now? Should I create another post for this question?

Comment: Enable debug logging to see what is going on. Also do you have the correct field names as I also mentioned? If they don't match your name will never be read and you are basically trying to login with no username and only a password!

Comment: Will enable debugging and figure it out. Yes, my field names are correct. Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things flawed in your setup.

1. You should post to `/login` instead of `/j_spring_security_check` as that is the new URL when using java config (and in Spring 4 for XML config also).
2. You have set the `usernameParameter` to `name` and your form still has `username`.

Fix those flaws in your login page.